# Complex eigenvalues and vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $A = \begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix}$. Then $ \begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix}$

A. is an eigenvector with eigenvalue 1.

B. is an eigenvector with eigenvalue -1.

C. is an eigenvector with eigenvalue i.

D. is an eigenvector with eigenvalue -i.

E. Is not an eigenvector

The answer is D. How do I get to that answer?

I think I correctly get the eigenvalues i, -i, but when I try to get the associated eigenvectors I get something very different.

When I solve for $\lambda = -i$, I get the matrix $\begin{pmatrix}-i& -1\\ 1& -i\end{pmatrix}$. After computing the solution, I get $ \begin{pmatrix}i\\1\end{pmatrix}$.

EDIT: I figured it out. I needed to set the free parameter to $-i$, which makes the first value in the eigenvector a 1.

Comment: Please use [MathJax].(https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)  Also, it would help a lot if you would show the "something very different" that you get, and how you get it.  It's hard to help you if you don't tell us what your difficulty is.

Comment: Compute $Av$ and check if is equal to $\lambda v$ for $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$

Comment: @MartínVacasVignolo You meant $\lambda \in \mathbb C$ didn't you?

Comment: Yes, a typo, i fixed it.

Comment: That's correct!  Just remember that eigenvectors are only defined up to a nonzero constant multiple.

Comment: `I think I correctly get the eigenvalues` You don't need those, it's enough to calculate:

$$\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix} \cdot \begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}-i\\-1\end{pmatrix} = \underbrace{(-i)}_{\text{eigenvalue}} \cdot \underbrace{\begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix}}_{\text{eigenvector}}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$\begin{pmatrix}0& 1\\ -1& 0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix} =  \begin{pmatrix}-i\\-1\end{pmatrix} =-i    \begin{pmatrix}1\\-i\end{pmatrix}         $$ Thus $-i$ is the eigenvalue.